# stripe elements tooltip "secure card number input frame"

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I updated my stripe elements UX, and somehow now when I hover on the card input fields I get a tooltip saying:

- "secure card number input frame",
- "secure expiration date input frame",
- "secure CVC input frame".

I'm not sure which of my changes got it to show these tooltips, but I don't need them.

here's my html:

```
  <div id="card-details">
    <div id="card-number">
      <label>Card number</label>
      <div id="card-number-input" class="input"></div>
    </div>
```

and javascript

```
        const stripe = Stripe(App.Config.stripeKey);
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {placeholder: '', style: style});
```

Any ideas on how to remove them?

Thanks

Comment: It appears stripe adds the attribute to the element. Does setting your own title make a difference?

Comment: It isn't possible to customize or remove the title attributes that Stripe adds to the embedded iframes. You can likely do so by manipulating the DOM manually, but I wouldn't risk it. For most users a tooltip won't show, and the tooltip is only visible under certain browser versions/settings anyway. Personally, I don't see a tooltip, and never have.

Comment: thanks for the idea of setting the title, I tried it but it just added a tooltip for the surrounding div, so the `secure .... frame` remained. the weird thing is that we don't get the tooltip in prod, only in the newer SCA ready version of it, even though I didn't change a thing (none that was obviously relevant at least) in the HTML or Javascript.